# How to shorten the command when filtering data-frame in Python

Tags: python

In Python, a common way to filter a data frame is like this

```
df.loc[(df['field 1'] == 'a') & (df['field 2'] == 'b'), 'field 3']...
```

When `df` name is long, or when there are more filter conditions (only two in the above), the above line will be long naturally. Moreover, it is a bit tedious to have type out `df` name for each condition. In R or SQL, we don't really need to do that. So, my question is if there is a way to shorten the above line in Python. For example, is there a way that I don't have to write down `df` name in each condition? Thanks.

Comment: try to break down your script by assigning each condition to a variable (mask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `query` method as follows which is has an SQL like syntax

```
df.query('field_1 == "a" and field_2 == "b" and field_3 > 3.2 ')
```

Here are the docs for it https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: What about adding links to your answer, e.g. docs for [`DataFrame.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) ?

Answer (score 3):

We can write a function that accepts lists of field names and conditions, [iterates in parallel](/questions/1663807) to create masks for each name-condition pair in a [generator expression](/questions/34835951), [combines](/questions/32132250/) those masks with `numpy.logical_and` (since we want to replicate `&`; it would be `logical_or` for `|`) - [skipping a redundant pair of parentheses due to a special syntax rule](/questions/9297653/) - and applies the result:

```
def matching(df, fields, values):
    return df.loc[np.logical_and(
        df[field] == value
        for field, value in zip(fields, values)
    )]
```

Which should then allow us to simplify the code:

```
matching(df, ['field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Alternately, we could specify the input as field-value pairs (and skip the `zip` step), as keys and values of a dictionary (iterating over its `.items()`), etc. The generalization of arbitrarily many `&`s using `numpy.logical_and` is the key insight here; the rest is just software engineering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dataframe.eval()` function. It can be done like below.

```py
df[df.eval("(field 1 == 'a') & (field 2 == 'b')")]
```